# Shortcut for centering the 3D-cursor in a view

Tags: 3d-view

[image]Is there a keyboard shortcut for centering the 3D-cursor in the current view? The cursor itself should stay in the same spot in space (i.e. its coordinates shouldn't change).

Right now I have to manually center the cursor using *shift + press scroll wheel*, which is tedious.

ADDED: the GIF shows that "Center view to cursor" does not work. The cursor remains out of center (left lower corner)

Answer (score 2):

There is a menu for that: *"Center view to cursor"*

[image]

But no predefined shortcut. You can assign the one you want with a right click on the menu (or add it to the quick favorites):

[image]

[image]

But that won't move it the view center is locked to 3d cursor's location:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but before asking the question, I had already tried "Center View to Cursor" in my project. It had NO effect. Weird, because now I tried it in a new project (the "Cube"), and it DOES work.

Comment: Maybe I've mistunderstood the question? What do you mean by " its coordinates shouldn't change" ? Should the view move or the cursor?

Comment: No, you understood right. I'm now toggling between my existing project and a new, empty ("cube") project. In the first it doesn't work, in the second it does (?!)

Comment: Well... in between... wanted to make sure!

Comment: Wanted to upload my GIF, but too big. It shows that the cursor stays in the left lower corner of the view, after clicking "Center View to Cursor".

Comment: Have uploaded GIF

Comment: Here is the explanation!

Comment: Found out myself just before your post, but thanks a lot! Blender can be a real jerk at times.

Comment: If that can help for gif ; ) https://www.screentogif.com/